# it there any way to store lambda with captured parameters in a pointer

Tags: c++, lambda

i have a problem with lambdas and is that i want to save them in pointers but create them using no constant variables.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<short n>
void speak(){
    std::cout << "speak:[" << n << "]" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    typedef void(*func)(void);

    func ptr[8];
    const short j = 10;
    
    for(short i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       ptr[i] = [=](void)->void{
            std::cout << "lamda:[" << j << "]" << std::endl;
            };
        /*ptr[i] = [=](void)->void{
            std::cout << "lamda:[" << i << "]" << std::endl;
            };*/
        ptr[i + 4] = speak<j>;
        //ptr[i + 4] = speak<i>;
    }
    
    for(short i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        ptr[i]();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It's posible to define a lambda with a constant var "j", but no with "i". Is there any way to do it using i, so there'll be no need to do:

```
ptr[0] = [=](void)->void{
            std::cout << "lamda:[" << 0 << "]" << std::endl;
            };
ptr[1] = [=](void)->void{
            std::cout << "lamda:[" << 1 << "]" << std::endl;
            };
ptr[2] = [=](void)->void{
            std::cout << "lamda:[" << 2 << "]" << std::endl;
            };
ptr[3] = [=](void)->void{
            std::cout << "lamda:[" << 3 << "]" << std::endl;
            };
```

*the templated function was my other attempt to achieve it, with no success*

*when i tried using "i" got: "error: cannot convert 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'func {aka void (*)()}' in assignment"*

Comment: What are you trying to do? why not assign it to std::function ?

Comment: Note the `j` case works because that lambda doesn't actually capture `j`. Change its `[=]` to `[]`, and everything is just the same. Only lambdas that don't capture anything can convert to raw function pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `std::function` instead of a pointer. Just include the header `<functional>`, and change

```
typedef void(*func)(void);
```

to

```
typedef std::function<void(void)> func;
```

and everything should work!

Not sure why you like to write `(void)` when `()` works too.

The reason you can't use a function pointer is because a function pointer just points to code; it doesn't have any captured variables. `std::function` is a class which is also able to hold the captured variables.

Comment: In C `(void)` and `()` are different, and usually `(void)` is what you mean. So maybe the habit comes from there. (In C++ there's no technical difference, and most people consider `()` better style.)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've read in other forums the same advice and was actually looking for a different way to aproach the problem, but i relaize it just silly to ignore this solution.